# Uploadify: Wait for move_uploaded_file until firing "onUploadSuccess"

Tags: php, uploadify

I'm trying to upload large video files via uploadify but once the files get big (>800MB) the onUploadSuccess event fires before `move_uploaded_file`is done. Is there a way to make uploadify wait for an actual succes or even display some kind of waiting message bewteen the finished upload and the actual success (like "finishing upload" or something)?
Here's the code of my upload.php:

```
if($video = wire('pages')->get($_POST['id'])) {
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $targetFile = preg_replace('/ /','_',$targetFile);
    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('mov','mp4','m4v'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)) {
            $file = preg_split("/\//", $targetFile);
            $video->filename = array_pop($file);
            $video->video_status = 'transcode';
            $video->addStatus('Page::statusUnpublished');
            $video->save();
            echo $video->filename." gespeichert";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
}
```

Thanks,
thomas